# EdgeRank for eCommerce product feed

Tags: r, python, graphical-model, recommender-system, igraph

I am running my eCommerce store with around 1000 products with 10 categories. I want to show these products in feeds. But there are lots of products so its very complex to define priority list for them. How can I optimize or make this feed as relevant to user.

By searching online, I have found that there is one algorithm - EdgeRank used by Facebook and LinkedIn for their feed optimization. I cant figure out how can I utilize for my dataset ?

Is there any case study with some calculation explained with proper theory? or is there any other approach ?

Comment: Found this via Google: http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/22/facebook-edgerank/

Comment: can you explain how to calculate affinity score ?